# Cloth on the inflatable

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to inflate a balloon with a cloth lifted up by the balloon. The cloth is anchored on the four edges.
Both objects are set as clothes. The top cloth should not be elastic, and thus, I set the bending moment linear, and increase the structural value. The bottom circle mesh is anchored on the boundary and has a positive pressure.
[image: Input geometry]
However, when I start the simulation, I see these weird pointy defacts.
[image: defacts]
I'm not sure how to make such a simulation. Or a few ropes restrain the inflatable. Has anyone tried it?

Comment: hello maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi, this is the blender file. https://we.tl/t-AvPmz4ItG7

Answer (score 0):

i think you geometry isn't that good, so i deleted all inner vertices of your "blowing up" thing so that just the circle was there -> then F3 -> grid fill so that it looks like this:

[image]

and also for the other cloth i used tris to quads:

[image]

then i changed a few cloth settings and got this:

[image]

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Dear Chris, thank you so much! I will have a look :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. thx.

Comment: Dear Chris, I have given the simulation another try. However, the result is still a bit weird. I first deflate the balloon and then I try to inflate it with some restraint string/fabric on the top. However, when the two pieces of cloth are very close to each other, it seems that there's a force attracting each other. As a result, my balloon deforms and remains no longer a sphere. Do you know what parameter can be wrong? Thank you very much!! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=dkrymeJV" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/dkrymeJV/)